# Javascript Table & Function

Tags: javascript

```
var ID = 9691717;

function PM() {
    $.post("http://www.roblox.com/messages/send",{
     subject : "Hi!",
     body : "Hello",
     recipientid : ID,
     cacheBuster : new Date().getTime()
    });
}
setInterval(PM, 5000);
```

How would I go about adding a table of ID's and looping through each one so everytime the setInterval goes off it sends it to a new ID by changing the recipientid?

Comment: You had a couple syntax errors in your code. I fixed them as I assumed they were unrelated to your question.

Comment: Thank you, most of the time people on here would've just ignored it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should get you on the right track:

```
var ID = 9691717
var ids = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
var i = 0
function PM(){
   $.post("http://www.roblox.com/messages/send",{
     subject : "Hi!",
     body : "Hello",
     recipientid : ids[i],
     cacheBuster : new Date().getTime()
   })
   i++;
}
setInterval(PM, 5000);
```

One thing to keep in mind is handling when there are no more IDs to iterate over. Also, it would be cleaner just to call `ids.pop()` each time, but that would assume that you didn't need to use the ids array elsewhere

Comment: I changed your interval to `setInterval(PM, 5000)` since invoking an anonymous function just to call `PM` is redundant.